# A forced 'bribe' payment i.e. an extortion payment is called what?

Tags: single-word-requests

> You get framed by corrupt police, go to jail or pay $10,000 ..........

This is extortion, but what is this **payment called?** It can't be called a **bribe** right? As bribery is the one paying trying to swerve justice. So what do we call it other than an **'extortion payment'**? "Or pay $10,000 bribe to avoid jail..." doesn't seem correct in this case. Although there is an article in The Guardian talking about people being 'forced to pay huge Bribes in Syria' i.e. extortion.

Comment: It would still be called a "bribe," I think. To me, "or pay a $10,000 bribe" sounds correct.

Comment: Wikipedia's article [police corruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_corruption) refers to such payments as bribes. [This academic paper about Russian traffic police](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S038611121500028X) uses the same term. There are a lot of euphemistic local terms in different countries, but nothing universal: the paper about Russia uses *pay "indulgences"* with quotes, but *bribes* without quotes.

Comment: The procedure could be called a "shakedown" but I think "bribe" is quite an appropriate term in this context. There are various euphemisms for (I think) less painful amounts such as "baksheesh" or "mordida" but I don't think they fit a $10,000 payment.

Comment: I suppose that if the sentence provides context that the 'bribe' is due to extortion, then 'bribe' can be used, although it is not the meaning of 'bribery'. I ran a search for 'extorted bribe' and a lot of news articles and legal documents included that term, but I wanted a one word term other than 'bribe' but I expect none exists.

Comment: "You are framed by police, go to jail or pay $10,000 bribe..." is perhaps better than "You are framed by police, go to jail or pay $10,000 extorted bribe..." as the sentence already implies the bribe is extorted (although in theory, the wording allows that the bribe being paid could be to another party, other than the one extorting in order to alleviate one's predicament) so maybe 'extorted bribe' is correct when there is no context to specify/clarify the type of bribe, whereas 'bribe' maybe correct when there is context.

Comment: One could go the route of 'booty' or 'loot', but this is usually said on the receiving end. If a pirate attacks your ship and takes booty, does someone also give them the booty? If so, something more along those lines, plundered money, may fit.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "ransom?" Or payout? Payola? Racket?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Answers should be answers to the question and not be general chatty sentiments. I have edited such material out. You should give reasons or sources for your suggestions, and not phrase your suggestions as questions. Read the site help guide to see how to answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience (not direct experience, mind you), a bribe is mutually arranged in order to benefit both parties and is not imposed as a requirement on one party. You might instead try "ransom" ([from M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ransom)):

> a consideration paid or demanded for the release of someone or something from captivity

In this case, you would paying your own ransom, i.e., for your own release from captivity. (Note that M-W's definition of the verb form of this word extends its meaning beyond the mere issue of captivity: "to free from captivity or punishment by paying a price".)

How appropriate this word is for your context probably depends on the exact nature of the situation (why the cops initiated the action in the first place, whether you've already been detained or not, etc.).

Comment: I think ransom applies in cases where the person is already in prison/captivity. An extorted bribe could apply to both cases i.e. either preventing imprisonment or freeing one from imprisonment.

Comment: @ZaydDepaor Yes, "ransom" definitely works better if "you've already been detained" (as I noted), but there's a lot of gray area. "Extorted bribe" might work except that I don't think that it's common (I don't recall ever hearing it) and it's two words (whereas your question is tagged as a SWR).

Answer (score -1):

As I mentioned in the comments, the word *bribe* is indeed correct in this context. [TFD defines it as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bribe)

> Money or some other benefit given to a person in power, especially a public official, in an effort to cause the person to take a particular action.